# How to get this dateformat in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Currently i have date in this format

```
cdate = 2016-06-29 23:45:42
```

I need to convert this date into this format

```
Wed 06/29/2016 11:45 PM
```

`new Date(cdate)` is giving me

```
Wed Jun 29 2016 23:45:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: You might consider checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) SO link. They got plenty of tips formatting dates.

Comment: Consider simply reformatting the string, it avoids the vagaries of the built-in parser and libraries. The provided format doesn't have a timezone, so treating it as local means that it will represent a different moment in time in each host with a different offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log(moment("2016-06-29 23:45:42").format("ddd MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to format the date using `format("ddd MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A")`

Comment: An answer should not involve a library that is not mentioned in the OP or tagged. If using a library, you should also provide the parse format.

Answer (score 0):

More complicated, but without the 3rd party library:

```
let formatted = (d => {
  // Convert the date to JS string representation and split on space
  let [dow, mn, dom, year, time] = new Date(d).toString().split(/\s/);
  // Extract the month from the original string
  let [mon] = d.split('-')[0];
  // Put month, day, year in desired format
  let datestring = `${mon}/${dom}/${year}`;
  // Extract the time parts, convert to numbers
  let [hr, min, sec] = time.split(':').map(Number);
  let [hour, am] = hr > 11 ? [hr - 12, 'PM'] : [hr, 'AM'];
  return `${dow} ${datestring} ${hour}:${min} ${am}`;
})(cdate);

console.log(formatted); // Wed 2/29/2016 11:45 PM
```

If you need to pad month/day with zeros you can use this helper function:

```
let padNumber = nstring => +nstring < 10 ? `0${nstring}` : nstring;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any library you can use Intl. It doesn't have DOW support but you can get it pretty easily.

```js
const date = new Date(2016, 05, 29, 11, 45);
const dow = ['Sunday','Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

console.log(`${dow[date.getDay()]} ${new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }).format(date)}`);

// or with short weekday name in the host default language

console.log(`${date.toLocaleString(undefined, {weekday:'short'})} ${date.toLocaleString(undefined, {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric', day: '2-digit'})}`);
```

Comment: Clever, but doesn't give the DOW.

Comment: @JaredSmith I added the DoW solution. It works as you want it.

Comment: Think the OP wanted the 3 char abbreviation rather than the full name. Still, +1 from me for using built-in features of the platform instead of pulling in a big 3rd party lib to do a simple format.

Comment: Re "*It doesn't have DOW support…*", yes it does, it's the *weekday* option.